# How to move images one after another in android application?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on android applicaiton. I need to start a second animation when the first animation is going on.

I need to move images one by one after some period of time. I have used framelayout with two imageViews in main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ars1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView2">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ars" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView1">
    </ImageView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Below is my animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
        android:duration="1500" />

</set>
```

in oncreate method of my activity class, i am doing something like below which is not working.

```
ImageView imageView1;
ImageView imageView2;
Animation tranOut;

     tranOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);

    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setAnimation(tranOut);

    imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView2.setAnimation(tranOut);
```

Please tell me how can i move the two images one after another.

Thanks
Jyoti

Answer (score 0):

Try using animation listener, use onAnimationEnd(), and then start the second one. see the following link for more on animation listener.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i have to start the second image when first image is moving. So i need to start animation of second image when first image's animation is going on not on end of first animation's end. Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot and finally did it using ImageSwitcher.

animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="150%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" 
        android:duration="1500" />

</set>
```

animation1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-150%p" 
         android:duration="1500"  />

</set>
```

helloworld.java:

```
public class helloworld extends Activity implements ViewFactory {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Animation rollIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
Animation rollOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation1);

final ImageSwitcher iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher01);

iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
iSwitcher.setInAnimation(rollIn);
iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(rollOut);
iSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);

// TODO: Change the image in ImageSwitcher on end of animation rollIn.

}
```

Above code is the basic code for implementing this functionality (images move one after another). You can modify this as per your requirement.